# how to display only 5 days of week, instead of 7

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-bootstrap

Hello Angular Bootstrap Calendar Team (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar),

I am having an issue on iOS, where your calendar week view is just too large to display events. So the events are unclickable in the end of the day.

Is there a possibility to display instead of a week, a part of the week, for an example 3 or 5 days depending on the display size?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a fork, that allows that - have a look at https://github.com/azachar/angular-bootstrap-calendar